# Reading latest value from a xively channel using python

Tags: python, xively

I have been attempting to find a way to read data correctly from a channel using the xively-python library. I tried retrieving current_value but it only seems to retrieve the initial value, even after changing the value in the channel in the Xively interface. For instance, the initial value in channel 'command' is "Exit". This is correctly retrieved and executed by my program. However, if I end the program, update the 'command' channel value to 'AA' and then restart my program, it still picks up 'Exit'. I have tested this over 10-15 minutes and ensured more than 20 seconds to ensure it updates correctly.

Looking at the API I can't seem to work out a way to do it. What I wish to do is retrieve the latest value for a given channel. I'm using the channel as a method to pass commands between unconnected devices. I would be looking to read the channel regularly.

A small note, I saw a similar issue that was posted a year ago but has not be answered.

EDIT: I only appear to read the current_value once at the beginning of the program based on the Xively HTTP requests feed, the code I am using is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#import serial library and sleep from the time library
import serial
from time import sleep
import xively
import requests
from datetime import datetime

#declare port and baud rate then open conn
port = '/dev/ttyAMA0'
baud = 9600
ser = serial.Serial(port=port, baudrate = baud)

#xively variables
FEED_ID = "1032676103"
API_KEY = "FZ2IOZkDW5ZXAITh6kqqUVkZEIBfNk6y2SKxgx4DDDVLxi46"

#xively connection function reutrning a datastream handle
def open_connection(feed,target):
    try:
        datastream = feed.datastreams.get(target)
        print("Channel " + target + " found!")
        return datastream
    except:
        datastream = feed.datastreams.create(target)
        print("Channel " + target + " not found,new channel created!")
        return datastream

#push function
def push(target,value):
    target.current_value = value
    target.at = datetime.utcnow()
    try:
        target.update()
    except requests.HTTPError as e:
        print "HTTPError({0}): {1}".format(e.errno,e.strerror)

#pop function
def pull():
    command = open_connection(feed,"Command")
    command.at = datetime.utcnow()
    sleep(0.2)
    #return target.get(datetime.utcnow())
    return command.current_value


#check status of board 1 relay A
def status_one():
    ser.write('aAARELAYA---')
    sleep(0.2)
    reply = ser.read(12)
    sleep(0.2)
    relayAA = reply[9:]
    relayAA = relayAA.strip('-')
    return relayAA   

#check status of board 2 relay A
def status_two():
    ser.write('aBBRELAYA---')
    sleep(0.2)
    reply = ser.read(12)
    relayBA = reply[9:]
    relayBA = relayBA.strip('-')
    return relayBA

#toggle boardAA relay A function
def toggle_aa():
    ser.write('aAARELAYATOG')
    sleep(0.2)
    reply = ser.read(12)
    print(reply)
    sleep(0.2)

#toggle boardBB relay A function
def toggle_bb():
    ser.write('aBBRELAYATOG')
    sleep(0.2)
    reply = ser.read(12)
    print(reply)
    sleep(0.2)    

#setup and initial push to Xively

ser.flushInput()

api = xively.XivelyAPIClient(API_KEY)
feed = api.feeds.get(FEED_ID)
oneastatus = open_connection(feed,"Relay_1A")
twoastatus = open_connection(feed,"Relay_2A")
hubstatus = open_connection(feed,"Relay_Data")
#command = open_connection(feed,"Command")
hub = 1
push(hubstatus,hub)

relayAA = status_one()
print(relayAA)
push(oneastatus,relayAA)
relayBA = status_two()
print(relayBA)
push(twoastatus,relayBA)


#loop section - command handling
while hub:

    #operator = pull(command)
    operator = pull()
    sleep(0.2)
    print(operator)

    #command to toggle AA
    if operator == 'AA':
        toggle_aa()
        sleep(0.2)
        relayAA = status_one()
        push(oneastatus,relayAA)
        sleep(0.2)

    #command to toggle BA
    if operator == 'BA':
        toggle_bb()
        sleep(0.2)
        relayBA = status_two()
        push(twoastatus,relayBA)
        sleep(0.2)

    #command to shutdown
    if operator == 'Exit':
        hub = 0


#close conn
push(hubstatus,hub) 
ser.close
```

As you can see, I initially attempted to create the 'command' variable connection once, then afterwards tried creating it inside the loop to see if it changed things. I need it to read the current_value of the channel as often as the data updates, or at least on a semi regular basis to allow commands to be sent and implemented.

Comment: It'd be quite great if you can provide a small piece of code that reproduces the issue. Seems like this might a bug in the Python library, perhaps you could also try reproducing this without using library and just making REST requests manually...

Comment: I can't post my code until tuesday, but in the meantime here is the structure of the code. I've added --- to indicate a non relevant section of the code (i.e. working prior to implementing the read)

#declare variables, establish connections to datastreams etc
---
command = open_connection("command")

#functions to call
---
---
---

def pull(datastream):
 return datstream.current_value
---
---

#Setup

---

#Enter main loop

while status:

 operator = pull(command)
 print(operator)
 
---
---
---

#close connection

Comment: Please edit the question and put the code there whenever you have it, it's impossible to read it in the comment.

Comment: Code is now in the original post with an explanation of how far I have got to date, thanks for any help!!!

Comment: Anyone able to help solve this issue? I'm not too proud to admit I have about 4 hours left to fix this and my efforts don't seem to be getting anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this in REPL and cannot see why you are having a problem.

```
[xively-python] 0 %> python
requPython 2.7.5 (default, Aug 25 2013, 00:04:04) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import xively
>>> FEED_ID = "1032676103"
>>> API_KEY = "FZ2IOZkDW5ZXAITh6kqqUVkZEIBfNk6y2SKxgx4DDDVLxi46"
>>> api = xively.XivelyAPIClient(API_KEY)
>>> f = api.feeds.get(FEED_ID)
>>> d = f.datastreams.get('Command')
>>> print(d.current_value)
Exit
```

I then modified the value on the Xively workbench to `Exit2` and it worked:

```
>>> d = f.datastreams.get('Command')
>>> print(d.current_value)
Exit2
```

I now flip the value back to `Exit` and that looks all good too:

```
>>> d = f.datastreams.get('Command')
>>> print(d.current_value)
Exit
```

Comment: Could it be an issue with the Python library implementation? I can't see a difference between your method and mine or your testing process. I'll try it again and see if it works.